# C variadic function: need to keep multiple va_list but old ones are overwritten by latest one

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I run this in MSVC v142.
I need to keep multiple `va_list` and then pass all of them in an array to another API.
However, the old `va_list` were getting overwritten by the newer one.

```
void toVaList(va_list *out, int count, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, count);
    vprintf("toVaList: %d %d\n", args);
    *out = args;
}

int main()
{
    va_list args1;
    toVaList(&args1, 2, 11, 22);
    vprintf("first va_list: %d %d\n", args1);
    va_list args2;
    toVaList(&args2, 2, 33, 44);
    vprintf("first va_list: %d %d\n", args1); //now args1 are overwritten
    vprintf("second va_list: %d %d\n", args2);
    va_end(args1);
    va_end(args2);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
toVaList: 11 22
first va_list: 11 22
toVaList: 33 44
first va_list: 33 44
second va_list: 33 44
```

Is it possible to resolve this issue?

Edit:

Now `memcpy` works for me. I copied the `va_list` to a separate memory and kept the original `va_list` in the function body wrapped by `va_start` and `va_end`. It looks like the copied `va_list` outside of the function body works well.

`vprintf` doesn't invalidate the `va_list` args, since it might have made a `va_copy` inside its implementation.

```
void toVaList1(va_list *out, int count, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, count);
    memcpy(out, args, 256);
    vprintf("toVaList1: %d %d\n", args);
    va_end(args);
}

int main()
{
    char args1[256];
    toVaList1((va_list *)args1, 2, 11, 22);
    vprintf("first va_list: %d %d\n", args1);
    char args2[256];
    toVaList1((va_list *)args2, 2, 33, 44);
    vprintf("first va_list: %d %d\n", args1);
    vprintf("second va_list: %d %d\n", args2);
    char args3[256];
    toVaList1((va_list *)args3, 2, 55, 66);
    vprintf("first va_list: %d %d\n", args1);
    vprintf("second va_list: %d %d\n", args2);
    vprintf("third va_list: %d %d\n", args3);
}
```

The output is

```
toVaList1: 11 22
first va_list: 11 22
toVaList1: 33 44
first va_list: 11 22
second va_list: 33 44
toVaList1: 55 66
first va_list: 11 22
second va_list: 33 44
third va_list: 55 66
```

Edit:

Briefly describe the scenario for this requirement.
We have a list of messages with id defined in XML, and an internal API that takes msgId and va_list as arguments, which uses va_arg() to read va_list:

```
ID   Message
1    This is a message containing integer %d and string %s.
2    This is another message containing double %f.
.....


void internalAPI_PrintMsg(int msgId, va_list ap)
{
    char resultMsg[512];
    //lookup message id in XML and substitute arguments
    //in the loop through found message body...
    switch(char)
    {
    case 'd': 
        int i = va_arg(ap, int);
        //substitute the integer
        break;
    case 'f':
        double d = va_arg(ap, double);
        //substitute the double
        break;
    ....
    }
    PrintResultMessage(resultMsg);
}
```

We already have API to print single message:

```
void printMsg(int msgId, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, msgId);
    internalAPI_PrintMsg(msgId, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

Now we need to support an API to print a group of messages:

```
typedef struct
{
    long id;
    char[256] args;
} msgData;
void printGroupMsg(msgData * msgArr, int msgCount) //this is the new API that requires multiple va_list
{
    //do some other stuff to start group messaging
    for (int i = 0; i < msgCount; ++i)
        internalAPI_PrintMsg(msgArr[i].id, msgArr[i].args);
    //do some other stuff to end group messaging
}

void initMsgData(msgData *msg, int msgId, ...) //this is equivalent to toVaList(...)
{
    msg->id = msgId;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, msgId);
    memcpy(msg->args, args, 256);
    va_end(args);
}

//client code:
msgData *arr = malloc(sizeof(msgData)*2);
initMsgData(arr, 1, 88, "test");
initMsgData(arr+1, 2, 123.456);
printGroupMsg(arr, 2);
```

Comment: You can't use a `va_list` outside of a function that it was created. This is because it doesn't copy the arguments in any way, so once the function returns, the arguments are gone too.

Comment: copy the args to your out pointer via memcpy!

Comment: Is it even possible to do something like `*out = args;` ?

Comment: @Arsenic — it depends on how `va_list` is defined.  Some implementations will allow it; others will not.

Comment: You can't use `va_list` after a call to `vprintf`. You can only call `va_end`.

Comment: This seems very convoluted.  Can you give a more concrete example of how you would use this?  I suspect this is an XY problem, i.e. there's a better way to accomplish what you actually want.

Comment: Maybe it helps to understand that `va_list` is really more of a `va_iterator`.  It doesn't actually store a copy of the arguments (typically), it only keeps track of which one we are currently looking at.  It may very well just be a single `int` or a pointer.  `va_arg` retrieves the actual arguments, and their lifetimes end when the function returns, just as for non-variadic arguments.  At that point your `va_list` is in essence a dangling pointer.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the C standard stipulates that if you invoke `va_start` in function, you must also invoke `va_end` in the same function:

> [§7.16.1 Variable argument list access macros](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.16.1)
>
> ¶1 The `va_start` and `va_arg` macros described in this subclause shall be implemented as macros, not functions. It is unspecified whether `va_copy` and `va_end` are macros or identifiers declared with external linkage. If a macro definition is suppressed in order to access an actual function, or a program defines an external identifier with the same name, the behavior is undefined. *Each invocation of the `va_start` and `va_copy` macros shall be matched by a corresponding invocation of the `va_end` macro in the same function.*

*[…Emphasis added…]*

Your `toVaList` function is violating that requirement and therefore invokes undefined behaviour.

The preamble to §7.16 says:

> 3 The type declared is
>
> ```
>     va_list
> ```
>
> which is a complete object type suitable for holding information needed by the macros `va_start`, `va_arg`, `va_end`, and `va_copy`. If access to the varying arguments is desired, the called function shall declare an object (generally referred to as `ap` in this subclause) having type `va_list`. The object `ap` may be passed as an argument to another function; if that function invokes the `va_arg` macro with parameter `ap`, the value of `ap` in the calling function is indeterminate and shall be passed to the `va_end` macro prior to any further reference to `ap`.<sup>253)</sup>
>
> <sup>253)</sup> It is permitted to create a pointer to a `va_list` and pass that pointer to another function, in which case the original function may make further use of the original list after the other function returns.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. Just made a memcpy of va_list to hack it.

Answer (score 1):

`va_copy` must be used in place of `*out = args;` to makes a copy of the `va_list` but it does not change the scope where it is valid to enumerate it, which is the called function.  Referring to the `va_list` after the function `toVaList` returns has undefined behavior.

This restriction is not specified explicitly in the C Standard. The relevent language is this:

> **7.16.1 Variable argument list access macros**
> ...
> Each invocation of the `va_start` and `va_copy` macros shall be matched by a corresponding invocation of the `va_end` macro in the same function.

This phrase means that `va_end()` must be called in the same function that called `va_start` or `va_copy` for the same `va_list` argument, hence this argument cannot be used once the function returns.

Your approach has undefined behavior per the C Standard. This is easy to understand from an implementation standpoint: calling a function with a variable number of arguments involves passing these arguments to the function in an implementation defined way that the variable argument accessing macros abstracts. Yet like any other function call, the arguments go out of scope when the function returns to its caller.  If you want to access them at some later point, you must enumerate them and save their values to an array or structure with an appropriate scope and life time.  The `memcpy` hack attempts to do this, but its behavior is undefined.

Here is an alternative approach:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int **array_from_args(int count, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, count);
    int *a = malloc(sizeof(*a) * (1 + count));
    if (a) {
        a[0] = count;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            a[i + 1] = va_arg(ap, int);
        }
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return a;
}

void print_array(const char *s, const int *a) {
    printf("%s:", s);
    if (a) {
        for (int i = 0, n = a[0]; i < n; i++)
            printf(" %d", a[i + 1]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    int *args1 = array_from_args(2, 11, 22);
    int *args2 = array_from_args(2, 33, 44);
    int *args3 = array_from_args(2, 55, 66);
    print_array("args1", args1);
    print_array("args2", args2);
    print_array("args3", args3);
    free(args1);
    free(args2);
    free(args3);
}
```

You could generalize this approach for arguments of different types by providing type information as an argument to the `array_from_args()`, like a `printf` format string, and construct an array of tagged structures.

Comment: What you're saying sounds right, but there are two things, which makes me wonder: 1. the standard says _'shall'_ and 2. the footnote 253: _"It is permitted to create a pointer to a va_list and pass that pointer to another function, in which case the original function may make further use of the original list after the other function returns."_. How do you think fit those together? Well, if i think about it, the answer would/could be, that the pointer should be to an initialized list (either via `va_start` or `va_copy` - with a matching `va_end`).

Comment: @ErdalKüçük: a pointer to the `va_list` can be passed to another function that can use it to retrieve some arguments, and then further used by another function or the calling function, all these for as long as the `va_list` is still in scope and any `va_arg` invocation matches the corresponding argument type.  For example an implementation of `printf` could call a specific function to handle the various conversion types, and these functions could retrieve the optional width and precision fields (if specified as `*` and passed as arguments) and the typed argument.

Comment: @ErdalKüçük: storing a pointer to the `va_list` is fine as long as it is only dereferenced and used in invocations of `va_arg` or `va_end` before the function returns.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot, that's what i've thought. I have to revise my answer then, because in that state it is not entirely correct (partly misleading).

Comment: Are you sure this is allowed by the C standard?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: can you be more specific?

Comment: I think my concern was misplaced — confused by the retention of the name `toVaList()` and the use of `"first va_list"` etc when the output is not a `va_list` but rather a simple dynamically allocated array of `int`.  So, you can ignore my concerns (except, perhaps, for the naming).  The function would be better named `fromVaList()` or `arrayFromVaList()` or thereabouts.  But somewhere along the line, it looks like compound literals would work as well as actual variable args functions.

Comment: @chqrlie, thanks, but your approach doesn't solve the problem, since it assumes all the arguments are integers. However, va_list can contain a list of any type.

Comment: @DF24: my approach is just an example. If the arguments can have different types, you need a way to tell the function what these types are. You cannot delay providing this information.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: thank you for your feedback. I updated the answer with more appropriate names and extra hints.